# Mirroring a tree

Tags: haskell

The assignment is to mirror a tree (so at every level the leftmost child becomes the rightmost etc.).

**Data structure:**

```
import Data.List

data Rose a = Node a [Rose a]
         deriving (Eq, Show)
```

**what I have come up so far:**

```
mirror :: Rose a -> Rose a
mirror (Node x []) = Node x []
mirror (Node x (y:ys)) = mirror (myReverse y)

--reverses given node children
myReverse :: Rose a -> Rose a
myReverse (Node x y) = Node x (reverse y)
```

So when I run this code with example:

```
Main> mirror (Node 1 [Node 11 [Node 111 [], Node 112[]], Node 12 [Node 121[]]])
```

the function returns me `Node 112 []` meaning it gets stuck on the leftmost leaf. Judging by my code it seems to be logical, because I'm not passing the tail of the given node children at `y:ys`. Somehow I have to be able to reverse all the children of the first children of given node **AND** pass the tail for the same function. No matter how hard I try I'm not able to achieve this and it looks like I have hit the limit of my logical thinking.

[Documentation for reverse function](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base-4.4.1.0/Data-List.html#v%3areverse)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would avoid thinking about it in small terms like the first child and the rest of the children. Instead, try to see the whole picture.

```
                a                             a
             /     \                       /     \
            b       c        ===>         c       b
          / | \    / \                   / \    / | \
         d  e  f   g  h                 h   g  f  e  d
```

If we think about this recursively, we can observe that we can mirror a tree by:

1. Reversing the order of the children.
2. Recursively mirroring the children themselves.

You already know how to use `reverse`. To apply a function `f` to every element in a list, you can use `map f`. Try to see if you can use these together to solve it for yourself.

**Spoiler:**

> `mirror (Node a children) = Node a (reverse $ map mirror children)`

Comment: Thank you, using the built in function `map` makes it a lot easier. Also, do I get it right that the $ sign means parenthesis? Without the $ sign the spoiler result would be `mirror (Node a children) = Node a (reverse (map mirror children))` ?

Comment: @SYLARRR: Yes, the `$` operator has very low precedence, so you can usually think of it like a big left parenthesis that extends as far to the right as possible.

Comment: Heh, this is the first time I've seen somebody use a spoiler on this site. Good job.

Answer (score 3):

As you correctly pointed out, you are not using `ys` at all in your `mirror` function, so the result cannot possibly be right.

To solve the problem, it helps to think of the recursive structure of `Rose`, and how mirroring affects it.

Namely, in order to mirror a tree, you have to keep its root, and (recursively) mirror each of its children, while reversing the order of said children.

If this is clear, then it's just a matter of translating those words into Haskell code.

Ask yourself:

1. How can I apply a function to each of the children and collect the results in a list?
2. How can I do 1 in reverse order?
3. Do I really need to handle the empty list case separately?

Comment: 1. To apply a function to all of the children, I have to recursively go them through. Taking the head of the list, applying function and passing on the body to the same function. How to collect all the custom data type results into a list - i don't know and that's what is causing me the problem...
2. running my helper function called `myReverse`
3. no, I don't

Comment: @SYLARRR To apply a function to every element of a list, use `map`: it does all the tedious recursing down the list, so you don't have to write it again.